# apt-cache search [emacs*+] doesnt find emacs in debian

Tags: emacs, debian, apt-get

I can't find the emacs package to install on debian.
I am using `apt-cache search [emacs*+]` and I get a list of packages which depend on emacs, but not emacs itself.

Any thoughts? I installed the Debian base system only.

Comment: The `[emacs*+]` looks strange to me. Shouldn't this just be `[emacs*]` or even `emacs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `[emacs*+]` doesn't make sense. Second, add more apt repositories. Just search for `emacs`, `emacs*+` is equivalent to an apt-cache search with `emac`.

Mine shows more than 300 entries matching emacs:

```
 # Correct search
 $ apt-cache search emacs | wc -l
 330

 # Wrong
 $ apt-cache search emacs*+ | wc -l
 333
```

Comment: Which apt repos should I add, I only want to use stable packages.

Comment: Try to execute `sudo apt-get update` and try apt-cache as I suggested first.

Comment: ran apt-get update, and now emacs shows up. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @bjg happy coding with emacs ;)